Function symbols in first order languages
Let's say $f$ is a unitary function symbol in a first order language (with equality). Then every structure $\mathfrak M$ with domain $| \mathfrak M |$ assigns a function $f^{\mathfrak M}: | \mathfrak M | \to | \mathfrak M |$ to this symbol. So, intuitively, I suppose that $\forall x \exists y (f(x)=y)$ holds in all models and is therefore a valid sentence.
Is this correct so far?
Now, take for example Peano arithmetic. Is $\exists y (S(0)=y)$ LK-derivable from the axioms? If it is, could you give me some pointers to how to derive it?

Of course it's derivable in LK - given that you formulated LK with function symbols (as usual) and equality rules (less usual). Since $\exists R$ lets you pick a term $t$ and derive the substitution instance $\varphi[x:=t]$ instead of $\exists x. \varphi$, you can start with $\vdash \exists y. S(0)=y$, apply  $\exists R$ to obtain $\vdash S(0)=S(0)$ then close the branch with the reflexivity right rule.

Thank you. I wasn't seeing the forest for the trees.

No worries. Note that if you want, you can fill in the details and post this as an answer: self-answers are permitted. You can also accept your own answer, however, you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better answer!
